# Error in "npm run dev" marzipano ' s demos

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install marzipano: https://github.com/google/marzipano
when I execute command line "npm run dev", it happen:

```
$ npm run dev

> marzipano@0.5.2 dev C:\Users\Clavis\Desktop\marzipano-master
> scripts/dev

'scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Clavis\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! marzipano@0.5.2 dev: `scripts/dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the marzipano@0.5.2 dev script 'scripts/dev'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the marzipano package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     scripts/dev
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs marzipano
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls marzipano
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Clavis\Desktop\marzipano-master\npm-debug.log
```

npm-debug.log: https://app.box.com/s/f0yxb2hiu49gp7rsgv5qm26auftm1zka

how to solve this error?

Comment: Can yo include  C:\Users\Clavis\Desktop\marzipano-master\npm-debug.log ?

Comment: You already have the latest stable node an npm versions installed so maybe it's a bug of marzipano on your system. I think it's a good idea to contact the project maintainers as suggested in the error message. Alternatively you could try to run this on a different environment (maybe a linux VM)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try